# Change R Installation Directory in RStudio

Tags: r, windows, installation, rstudio

I am on R-3.3.0 and set up RStudio. This is the output I get when I try to find the version in RStudio

```
> version
               _                           
platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          3.0                         
year           2016                        
month          05                          
day            03                          
svn rev        70573                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
nickname       Supposedly Educational
```

I want to change it to point to the R-2.5.1 instance I have installed in my machine. How do I go about this?

Comment: Just click Tools -> Global Options and then pick the R installation you want

Comment: @Hack-R Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sure np glad to help

Comment: If you hold down `Ctrl` key and  then doubleclick RStudio icon, a popup will appear where you can choose which R version you want to use.